# How can I launch a ray server in a linux/amd64/x86_64 docker container running on a macOS arm64/M1/Apple Silicon - without crashing?

Tags: docker, x86-64, cross-compiling, ray, apple-silicon

I have a ray server running successfully inside a docker (docker engine 24.0.6) [docker desktop: 4.25.2 (129061)] container on my M1 (Sonoma 14.1) as arm64.

On the M1, I need to create - and successfully test - an amd64 version for cloud deployment (where arm64 chipsets are not an option for me - nice try :) ).

How can I achieve this?

The situation I am up against is given here:

https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/28103#issuecomment-1363478818

The error logs - from a range of locations - differ between settings and are a function of: Rosetta2 vs not, containerd vs not, Virtualization framework vs not. In the best case I get the output at the foot of the question.

Here's my self-contained Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl

RUN echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

# Install Ray package
RUN pip install grpcio==1.54.2
#RUN pip install --no-cache-dir ray[default]
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ray-wheels/latest/ray-3.0.0.dev0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

# Create the start_ray.py script
RUN echo '#!/usr/bin/env python\n\nimport ray\nimport time\nimport threading\n\ndef start_ray():\n    ray.init(num_cpus=8, num_gpus=1)\n    while True:\n        time.sleep(1)\n\nthreading.Thread(target=start_ray).start()' > start_ray.py

# Create the ray_client.py script
RUN echo 'import ray\n\n@ray.remote\ndef f(x):\n    return x * x\n\nfutures = [f.remote(i) for i in range(10)]\nprint(ray.get(futures))' > ray_client.py

# Make port 6379 and 8265 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 6379
EXPOSE 8265

ENV RAY_BACKEND_LOG_LEVEL=debug

# Run ray when the container launches
RUN chmod +x start_ray.py
#CMD /bin/bash -c "./start_ray.py"
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "3600"]
```

I build it via

```bash
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t ray-docker:latest . --load
```

and to run a container I do:

```bash
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -it -p 6379:6379 -p 8265:8265 --shm-size=4.0gb --name ray_container ray-docker:latest
```

For testing I currently execute

```bash
docker exec -it ray_container /bin/bash
./start_ray.py
```

This provokes the error below.

Some points:

1. I don't want to just compile the amd64 image, deploy and hope for the best. There must be a way!
2. I've tried

(a) Increasing RAM/CPU resources for docker

(b) Adjusting ports etc.

(c) Explicitly pip installing grpc==1.54.2. Since that didn't work I followed the conda instructions at https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-overview/installation.html#m1-mac-apple-silicon-support - but using the ray wheel at https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ray-wheels/latest/ray-3.0.0.dev0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

(d) Adjusting containerd, Virtualization framework, Rosetta, ... you name it...

(e) This (another conda variant): https://github.com/Nixtla/neuralforecast/issues/621#issue-1746832296

Please assist!

```
root@0225b670c8e8:/app# ./start_ray.py
2023-11-30 11:41:32,431 WARNING worker.py:1371 -- SIGTERM handler is not set because current thread is not the main thread.
Usage stats collection is enabled by default for nightly wheels. To disable this, run the following command: `ray disable-usage-stats` before starting Ray. See https://docs.ray.io/en/master/cluster/usage-stats.html for more details.
2023-11-30 11:41:39,292 INFO worker.py:1700 -- Started a local Ray instance.
[2023-11-30 11:41:39,413 I 14 18] logging.cc:230: Set ray log level from environment variable RAY_BACKEND_LOG_LEVEL to -1
(raylet) Raylet is terminated. Termination is unexpected. Possible reasons include: (1) SIGKILL by the user or system OOM killer, (2) Invalid memory access from Raylet causing SIGSEGV or SIGBUS, (3) Other termination signals. Last 20 lines of the Raylet logs:
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,427 D 77 101] (raylet) store.cc:523: Finishing create object dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000 request ID 5
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,450 D 77 101] (raylet) store.cc:282: sealing object dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,450 D 77 77] (raylet) object_manager.cc:193: Object added dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,450 D 77 77] (raylet) ownership_based_object_directory.cc:126: Object dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000 does not have owner. ReportObjectAdded becomes a no-op.This should only happen for Plasma store warmup objects.
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,451 D 77 77] (raylet) node_manager.cc:2206: Object local dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000,  on be062f99f3d77d4d95c13ca6f4c24a6685b33f740d869ef6aa84f0f2, 0 tasks ready
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,451 D 77 101] (raylet) store.cc:258: Object dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000 no longer in use by client, should_unmap = 0
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,451 D 77 101] (raylet) object_lifecycle_manager.cc:157: Releasing object no longer in use dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000, num bytes in use is now 0
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,452 D 77 77] (raylet) node_manager.cc:1202: [Worker] Message FreeObjectsInObjectStoreRequest(17) from worker with PID nil
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,452 D 77 101] (raylet) plasma_allocator.cc:121: deallocating 8 at 0x40111ab040
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,453 D 77 77] (raylet) ownership_based_object_directory.cc:149: Object dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000 does not have owner. ReportObjectRemoved becomes a no-op. This should only happen for Plasma store warmup objects.
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,453 D 77 77] (raylet) node_manager.cc:2263: Object missing dfeabebaaba3487552b3fd35012af7cfb562565f1ab77cbb00000000,  on be062f99f3d77d4d95c13ca6f4c24a6685b33f740d869ef6aa84f0f2, 0 tasks waiting
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,472 D 77 77] (raylet) node_manager.cc:1202: [Worker] Message AnnounceWorkerPort(6) from worker with PID nil
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,567 D 77 77] (raylet) worker_pool.cc:1069: Idle workers: 4, idle workers that are eligible to kill: 0, num desired workers : 8
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,768 D 77 77] (raylet) worker_pool.cc:1069: Idle workers: 4, idle workers that are eligible to kill: 2, num desired workers : 8
    [2023-11-30 11:41:46,968 D 77 77] (raylet) worker_pool.cc:1069: Idle workers: 4, idle workers that are eligible to kill: 3, num desired workers : 8
    [2023-11-30 11:41:47,139 D 77 77] (raylet) gcs_rpc_client.h:521: GCS channel status: 2
    [2023-11-30 11:41:47,168 D 77 77] (raylet) worker_pool.cc:1069: Idle workers: 4, idle workers that are eligible to kill: 3, num desired workers : 8
    [2023-11-30 11:41:47,368 D 77 77] (raylet) worker_pool.cc:1069: Idle workers: 4, idle workers that are eligible to kill: 4, num desired workers : 8
    [2023-11-30 11:41:47,569 D 77 77] (raylet) worker_pool.cc:1069: Idle workers: 4, idle workers that are eligible to kill: 4, num desired workers : 8
    [2023-11-30 11:41:47,770 D 77 77] (raylet) worker_pool.cc:1069: Idle workers: 4, idle workers that are eligible to kill: 4, num desired workers : 8

(raylet) [2023-11-30 11:41:48,121 E 77 121] (raylet) agent_manager.cc:70: The raylet exited immediately because one Ray agent failed, agent_name = runtime_env_agent.
(raylet) The raylet fate shares with the agent. This can happen because
(raylet) - The version of `grpcio` doesn't follow Ray's requirement. Agent can segfault with the incorrect `grpcio` version. Check the grpcio version `pip freeze | grep grpcio`.
(raylet) - The agent failed to start because of unexpected error or port conflict. Read the log `cat /tmp/ray/session_latest/logs/{dashboard_agent|runtime_env_agent}.log`. You can find the log file structure here https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-observability/ray-logging.html#logging-directory-structure.
(raylet) - The agent is killed by the OS (e.g., out of memory).
```

That error seems related to (a merged fix at) https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/31421

Sometimes I rather get:

```
root@51cc5014b360:/app# cat /tmp/ray/session_latest/logs/runtime_env_agent.log
2023-11-29 14:52:26,910 INFO runtime_env_agent.py:238 -- Starting runtime env agent at pid 134
2023-11-29 14:52:26,926 INFO runtime_env_agent.py:239 -- Parent raylet pid is 91
2023-11-29 14:52:26,930 INFO runtime_env_agent.py:240 -- Listening to address 172.17.0.3, port 58195
2023-11-29 14:52:28,581 INFO main.py:198 -- Raylet is dead! Exiting Runtime Env Agent. addr: 172.17.0.3, port: 58195
2023-11-29 14:52:28,659 INFO main.py:219 -- SystemExit! 0
```